# Axial symmetry and identical circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$$\triangle ABC$$
$$AA_1, BB_1, CC_1 - h$$ 
$$AA_1 \cap BB_1 \cap CC_1 = H $$
$k(O; r)-$ circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$

$k_1(0_1; r_1) -$ circumcircle of $\triangle AHB$

Show that $k \cong k_1$.

### [image]

$A, B \in k$, thus $OA=OB=r$, thus $O \in S_c$

$A, B \in k_1$, thus $O_1A=O_1B=r_1$, thus $O_1 \in S_c$, thus $OO_1 \equiv S_C$

$OO_1 \bot AB, OO_1 \cap AB = P : AP=PB$.

I don't know how from here to show that $AO = AO_1$. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier: reflect $H$ in $AB$ to a point $H'$.  We will show that $H'$ lies on the circumcircle of $ABC$, hence the circumradius of $ABC=ABH'$ and $ABH$ are equal.

We have $\angle HAB=90^\circ-\angle ABC$, $\angle HBA=90^\circ-\angle CAB$.
Hence
$$
\angle AH'B=
\angle AHB=180^\circ-\angle HAB-\angle HBA =\angle ABC + \angle CAB = 180^\circ - \angle ACB
$$
so $AH'BC$ concyclic, i.e., $H'$ lies on the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't understand what's the point of showing that $H'$ lies on the circumcircle of $ABC$.

Comment: Then we get the circumcircle of $AH'B$ coincides with the circumcircle of $ABC$.  That way, the circumcircle of $AHB$ is simply reflecting the circumcircle of $ABC$ in the line $AB$, so they have the same radius and thus are congruent.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. Can I ask when the circumcircles of equal triangles coincide? I didn't know that. When they have a common side or?

Comment: You mean when $k$ and $k_1$ coincide?  That only happens when $AB$ is the diameter, i.e., when $C=90^\circ$.

Comment: No, when the circumcircle of $AH′B$ coincides with the circumcircle of $ABC$?

Comment: They are always the same circle.  In fact you get more, see e.g. [Orthocentric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_system)

Comment: Thank you but why $\angle AH'B = \angle AHB$? I don't see why these triangles are equal.

Comment: $H'$ is obtained by reflecting $H$ in $AB$, so $\triangle AH'B\cong\triangle AHB$ by definition.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the questions, but I want to understand fully. Why when we know that $\angle AHB = \angle AH'B = 180^\circ - \angle ACB$ we can state that the quadrilateral is cyclic? We should get $\angle AHB + \angle AH'B = 180^\circ$, right?

Comment: Opposite angle add up to $180^\circ$ is one of the ways we can tell a quadrilateral is cyclic.  No, $\angle AHB$ and $\angle AH'B$ need not add up to 180 degrees.